# Firebase Saving Data Gets Slower Over Time

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a card game (in Unity using Photon for networking) and storing the current hand of each user in Firebase. Over the course of a game, saving and updating this card data gets slower and slower until it's completely unplayable and takes up to 10 seconds just to update the cards.

I've tried recreating the problem but haven't been successful yet. At first I thought maybe the problem was with Photon but I've managed to basically narrow it down to firebase being incredibly slow.

I've essentially done something like this:

```
Debug.Log("About to set new hand order");

await FirebaseData.Instance.reference.Child("rooms").Child(currentRoom).Child("users").Child(playerUID).Child("hand").SetRawJsonValueAsync(cardArrayJson);

Debug.Log("Finished setting new hand order");
```

I've also timestamped the two log statements and seen that the time between them keeps on increasing over the course of a game. After stopping the program and restarting, it's fast again, until it again starts slowing down.

I plan to keep on trying different things to see if I'm doing something wrong, but I though I would ask in case it's something obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? In other words: is Firebase able to save the data to the server. If not, that could explain the slowness, as performance will get worse as there are more offline pending writes to process.

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to the internet. It is consistently getting slower over time, each time. It isn't an issue with my connection.